# How do I create an orbit in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, geometry, libgdx

I'm making a space game, and I'd like to make a small drone ship orbit my bigger player ship. I'm not entirely sure how to make it orbit in a perfect circle. So far I can make it move in a diamond shape, but my attempts to correct for the circle shape have ended in failure.

Basically, I'm doing something like this:

```
float centerX = ship.getX() + (ship.getWidth() / 2);
float centerY = ship.getY() + (ship.getHeight() / 2);
float droneX = drone.getX();
float droneY = drone.getY();
float radius = drone.getRadius();
float xDiff = Math.abs(droneX - centerX);
float yDiff = Math.abs(droneY - centerY);
float moveByX = Math.abs(radius / (xDiff == 0 ? 1 : xDiff) / smoother);
float moveByY = Math.abs(radius / (yDiff == 0 ? 1 : yDiff) / smoother);
```

And then I move the drone by the moveByX and moveByY values. It works fine in a diamond shape, as I mentioned, but how can I improve this to calculate the correct circular pattern?

Comment: by diamond you mean similar to a baseball diamond, where it's a square but rotated?

Comment: That's correct, yeah. That's the current behavior anyway...

Comment: I think you may need to put the trigonometry boots on, I'd give you the methods but I can't remember them for java/libgdx (I've never used the libgdx)

Comment: Okay, I had to look it up, but this is what might work. You'll have to get the angle kept somewhere (and in radians): droneX = drone.getRadius() * sin(angle); droneY = drone.getRadius()*cos(angle);

Comment: @CBredlow, I posted an answer to my question, but your comment led me to the answer. If you post your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Okay, I was using the FloatMath from Android's documentation, forgot about Math in java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, since you're using x and y differences, it will only go in a straight line, which explains the diamond pattern. In order to get the circle, you'll have to break out trigonometry.

```
float angle; //angle in radians
float droneX = drone.getRadius() * Math.sin(angle); 
float droneY = drone.getRadius() * Math.cos(angle);
```

After that you can use your movement code.  And angle should probably be kept on the drone, and in radians.

Answer (score 2):

CBredlow was able to give me enough information to solve the question - I wasn't able to accept his answer, as it was a comment, but the solution is this:

```
// this is degrees per second
   float speed = 10f;
   float rate = 5f;
   float circleX = (float) (Math.cos(drone.getAngle()) * 
          (ship.getWidth() / 1.25) + centerX);
   float circleY = (float) (Math.sin(drone.getAngle()) * 
          (ship.getHeight() / 1.25) + centerY);
   float angle = drone.getAngle() + (speed * (rate/1000)) % 360;
   if (angle >= 360) {
      angle = 0;
   }
   drone.setAngle(angle);
   drone.setX(circleX);
   drone.setY(circleY);
```

Thanks!